# How to stop workers in Celery?

Tags: celery

I'm trying to make periodic tasks using Celery in my Django project. I'm very struggling to understand how Celery works, and now it started showing something, but I don't know how to stop workers.

At fist, I run this command to start Celery beat.

```
celery -A proj beat
```

and then, run this command to start a worker

```
celery -A proj worker -B
```

No matter what I do, previous workers are still working. Even though I updated codes and stop the worker with `Ctrl+c`, they are still running. How can I stop all of them?

```
[2018-07-25 15:53:49,694: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-2] Yo
[2018-07-25 15:53:50,224: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-3] hello
[2018-07-25 15:53:52,694: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-2] Yo
[2018-07-25 15:53:55,694: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-3] Yo
[2018-07-25 15:53:58,694: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-2] Yo
[2018-07-25 15:54:00,227: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-3] world
[2018-07-25 15:54:00,229: WARNING/ForkPoolWorker-2] hello
```

Answer (score 3):

Shutdown should be accomplished using the TERM signal.

Method1:

```
$ pkill -9 -f 'celery worker'
```

Method 2:

```
$ ps auxww | grep 'celery worker' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9
```

Official Document: [here](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/workers.html#stopping-the-worker)

Comment: Worked for me, though I had to add the `--app=xyz` part to the grep command to make it work: `grep celery --app=cl worker`