# How to create alias command to stop celery

Tags: linux, celery, alias, oh-my-zsh

Following [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51562961/6560773) from another post I've made an alias in my `.zshrc` (I use [ohmyzsh](https://ohmyz.sh/)) to stop my celery workers:

```sh
alias stopcelery="ps auxww | grep 'celery' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9"
```

However when I have running celery workers, using this command fails:

```sh
➜ stopcelery
kill: invalid argument 

Usage:
 kill [options] <pid> [...]

Options:
 <pid> [...]            send signal to every <pid> listed
 -<signal>, -s, --signal <signal>
                        specify the <signal> to be sent
 -l, --list=[<signal>]  list all signal names, or convert one to a name
 -L, --table            list all signal names in a nice table

 -h, --help     display this help and exit
 -V, --version  output version information and exit

For more details see kill(1).
```

The workers are still running:

```sh
➜ ps auxww | grep 'celery'
myuser    49126 67.0  0.5 189132 92280 ?        S    15:59   0:02 /home/myuser/.local/share/virtualenvs/myproject-JLNbaOhA/bin/python -m celery worker -A wsgi.celery --loglevel=INFO --logfile=/tmp/celery.log --pidfile=celeryd.pid
myuser    49304  0.0  0.5 188160 85060 ?        S    15:59   0:00 /home/myuser/.local/share/virtualenvs/myproject-JLNbaOhA/bin/python -m celery worker -A wsgi.celery --loglevel=INFO --logfile=/tmp/celery.log --pidfile=celeryd.pid
myuser    49305  0.0  0.5 188164 84844 ?        S    15:59   0:00 /home/myuser/.local/share/virtualenvs/myproject-JLNbaOhA/bin/python -m celery worker -A wsgi.celery --loglevel=INFO --logfile=/tmp/celery.log --pidfile=celeryd.pid
myuser    49306  0.0  0.5 188168 84848 ?        S    15:59   0:00 /home/myuser/.local/share/virtualenvs/myproject-JLNbaOhA/bin/python -m celery worker -A wsgi.celery --loglevel=INFO --logfile=/tmp/celery.log --pidfile=celeryd.pid
myuser    49307  0.0  0.5 188172 84844 ?        S    15:59   0:00 /home/myuser/.local/share/virtualenvs/myproject-JLNbaOhA/bin/python -m celery worker -A wsgi.celery --loglevel=INFO --logfile=/tmp/celery.log --pidfile=celeryd.pid
myuser    49312  0.0  0.0  20556  2924 pts/8    S+   15:59   0:00 grep --color=auto --exclude-dir=.bzr --exclude-dir=CVS --exclude-dir=.git --exclude-dir=.hg --exclude-dir=.svn --exclude-dir=.idea --exclude-dir=.tox celery
```

But using the actual command it works:

```sh
➜ ps auxww | grep 'celery' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9
kill: (48078): No such process
```

Indeed, checking again:

```sh
➜ ps auxww | grep 'celery'                                   
myuser    49782  0.0  0.0  20556   664 pts/8    S+   16:03   0:00 grep --color=auto --exclude-dir=.bzr --exclude-dir=CVS --exclude-dir=.git --exclude-dir=.hg --exclude-dir=.svn --exclude-dir=.idea --exclude-dir=.tox celery
```

So what is the difference, why using the alias does not having the same effect?

Comment: You need to escape $ like `\$2` in your alias definition because you used double quotes.

Comment: I would not call this "stopping" Celery, but basically killing all Celery processes...

Comment: @DejanLekic That is true actually. I named it because that's the solution I've found for stopping celery. As for now I don't know if there is any built-in commands to actually stop the workers instead of just killing the processes. But eventually I just want them gone.

Comment: It boils down to sending SIGTERM (related thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67344425/celery-check-if-worker-received-sigterm) to the worker, and waiting for the process to stop for some period. If that period is reached and it is still up and running, then kill it the way you described.

Answer (score 0):

As @Philippe has pointed out, I forgot to escape the `$` sign as I was using double quotes.